# dynamic XSLT Transformation

Tags: xslt

I have an incoming simple xml request below and need to transform to below SOAP message with correct name space.and in the incoming XML request the name space are not coming so while forming the SOAP message we need to take care of the name space also. Is there any XSLT code snippet which will help me to achieve that.
Note - We need to do this XSLT transformation dynamically like the incoming request can be any element like "GetImageRequest" so based on this element need to construct the name space. (probably we can keep all the name space in one xml file and need to construct the SOAP message)

Incoming XML request:

```
<request>
<payload>
<GetImageRequest>
   <participantId>1191152220010</participantId>
   <participantCode>131029</participantCode>
   <groupCode>027198</groupCode>
   <userType>EE</userType>
   <clientName>Test</clientName>
   <shoeboxID>123444</shoeboxID>
   <imageID>45235</imageID>
</GetImageRequest>
</payload>
</request>
```

==================
Need to Construct below SOAP message with proper namespace.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>

   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <get:GetShoeboxItemRequest xmlns:get="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/GetShoeboxItem">
         <get:participantId>1060687620010</get:participantId>
         <get:participantCode>1060687620010</get:participantCode>
         <get:groupCode>027198</get:groupCode>
         <get:userType>EE</get:userType>
         <get:clientName>Test</get:clientName>
         <get:shoeboxID>123444</get:shoeboxID>
      </get:GetShoeboxItemRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Need a quick help on this . XSLT code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: "*based on this element need to construct the name space*" That's not clear enough. Please provide an exact rule for constructing  the namespace. I don't see the logic by which `GetImageRequest` becomes `"urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/GetShoeboxItem"`. --- P.S. Is [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194911/xslt-transformation-from-soap) answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pRequestedItemName" select="'Shoebox'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLcItemName" select=
                "translate($pRequestedItemName, $vUpper, $vLower)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDynNamespace" select=
   "concat('urn:webservice/server/mobile/', $vLcItemName, '/types/v1/Get', 'Item')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
              <xsl:element name="get:Get{$pRequestedItemName}ItemRequest" 
                   namespace="{$vDynNamespace}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/GetImageRequest/node()"/>
              </xsl:element>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="get:{name()}" namespace="{$vDynNamespace}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<request>
    <payload>
        <GetImageRequest>
            <participantId>1191152220010</participantId>
            <participantCode>131029</participantCode>
            <groupCode>027198</groupCode>
            <userType>EE</userType>
            <clientName>Test</clientName>
            <shoeboxID>123444</shoeboxID>
            <imageID>45235</imageID>
        </GetImageRequest>
    </payload>
</request>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <get:GetShoeboxItemRequest
         xmlns:get="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/GetItem">
         <get:participantId>1191152220010</get:participantId>
         <get:participantCode>131029</get:participantCode>
         <get:groupCode>027198</get:groupCode>
         <get:userType>EE</get:userType>
         <get:clientName>Test</get:clientName>
         <get:shoeboxID>123444</get:shoeboxID>
         <get:imageID>45235</get:imageID>
      </get:GetShoeboxItemRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The full power of the **[`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element)** instruction is used.
2. Use of **AVT** (**[Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**)
3. The only variable part of the dynamic namespace should be provided as **[a global parameter](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#top-level-variables)** by the invoker of the transformation.

If you need to construct a completely dynamic namespace (such as passed in a global parameter by the invoker of the transformation), see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796315/36305)**.

---

**UPDATE**:

The OP clarified in a comment that he can have all request-specific namespaces collected in a separate XML document or in a global parameter.

**Here is the solution to this clarified problem**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pRequestData">
   <r name="GetImageRequest" 
    ns="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/GetShoeboxItem"/>
   <r name="SaveShoeBoxitemRequest" 
    ns="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/SaveShoeboxItem"/>
   <r name="SaveClaimWithReceiptRequest" 
    ns="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/SaveClaimAndReceipt"/>
   <r name="GetThumbNailImageRequest" 
    ns="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/GetThumbnail"/>
   <r name="AttachReceiptwithExistingClaimRequest" 
    ns="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/AttachClaimAndReceipt"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vParams" select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pRequestData']"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*"/>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="pKey" select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:element name="get:{local-name()}" namespace="{$vParams/*[@name = $pKey]/@ns}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="pKey" select="$pKey"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one with a second, differently named child of `payload`):

```
<request>
    <payload>
        <GetImageRequest>
            <participantId>1191152220010</participantId>
            <participantCode>131029</participantCode>
            <groupCode>027198</groupCode>
            <userType>EE</userType>
            <clientName>Test</clientName>
            <shoeboxID>123444</shoeboxID>
            <imageID>45235</imageID>
        </GetImageRequest>
        <SaveShoeBoxitemRequest>
            <participantId>1191152220010</participantId>
            <participantCode>131029</participantCode>
            <groupCode>027198</groupCode>
            <userType>EE</userType>
            <clientName>Test</clientName>
            <shoeboxID>123444</shoeboxID>
            <imageID>45235</imageID>
        </SaveShoeBoxitemRequest>
    </payload>
</request>
```

**The wanted, correct (unlike "solutions" in other answers) result is produced**:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <get:GetImageRequest 
xmlns:get="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/GetShoeboxItem">
             <get:participantId>1191152220010</get:participantId>
             <get:participantCode>131029</get:participantCode>
             <get:groupCode>027198</get:groupCode>
             <get:userType>EE</get:userType>
             <get:clientName>Test</get:clientName>
             <get:shoeboxID>123444</get:shoeboxID>
             <get:imageID>45235</get:imageID>
          </get:GetImageRequest>
          <get:SaveShoeBoxitemRequest 
xmlns:get="urn:webservice/server/mobile/shoebox/types/v1/SaveShoeboxItem">
             <get:participantId>1191152220010</get:participantId>
             <get:participantCode>131029</get:participantCode>
             <get:groupCode>027198</get:groupCode>
             <get:userType>EE</get:userType>
             <get:clientName>Test</get:clientName>
             <get:shoeboxID>123444</get:shoeboxID>
             <get:imageID>45235</get:imageID>
          </get:SaveShoeBoxitemRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks for your reply. I need the XSLT to be dynamic like if any oot relement comes under "Payload" tag it should construct the soap envelope accordingly. like here we are constructing only for"GetImageRequest". How we can do that in XSLT. Need your help to do this.

Comment: @user5458829, This would be possible, if you specify the rule how to construct the name of the top-level generated element (such as "`<GetShoeboxItemRequest>`") from the corresponding child of `<payload>`, and also, how to construct the namespace string-value from the same corresponding element in the source xml document. These can all be provided as a global parameter, if a stable convention is not possible.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks for your comment

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks for your comment Like i have 5 possible incoming request under "payload" 1. GetImageRequest" 2. "SaveShoeBoxitemRequest" 3. "SaveClaimWithReceiptRequest" 4. "GetThumbNailImageRequest and 5. "AttachReceiptwithExistingClaimRequest" which is coming under the "payload"  element and while coming those incoming XML they are not sending the namespace for those 5 elements. So if i know what all namespace for those 5 elements i can put in one xml file and can retrieve from that XML file. or as you mentioned can define those name space in global document. XSLT code snippet would help.

Comment: Just to update if i have "GetImageRequest" element is coming under"payload" then the same element we need to construct in SOAP message under BODY.

Comment: @user5458829, I am going to work in minutes -- will look into this after 10-12 hours. Yes, it seems this can be done and I'll show one way to do this in my updated answer.

Comment: @user5458829 You should add these clarifications to your question.

Comment: @user5458829, I updated my answer with a solution that works correctly when the source XML document contains differently named (and even more than one) children of `<payload>`. Please, feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitre,

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitre, It works perfectly, But there is another possible scenario i came across while doing this. Like Lets say i have 2 simple elements and one complex element under the root tag . And there were 2 namespace like "ns="urn:webservice/abc" and "ns1="urn:webservice/def " . and some elements have ns0 name space prefix and some are having ns1 namespace prefix under root element. So how we can identify which element is having which namespace prefix. And how we can add those namespace prefix to incoming XML element. Can you Please check how it can be done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I have accepted your answer by clicking the tick button, Thanks  a lot for reply. So for the new scenario which i mentioned do i need to ask it in a new thread or we can continue with the same one. Please let me know so that i will do accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @user5458829, It would be cleaner to ask it I a new question. Just send me a comment with the link to this new question.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, Please find the below link to the new question.Link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @user5458829, Please, provide a correct link -- the one in your comment is to a general page where everyone can ask a question. Also, in your profile page there are only 2 questions you have asked, and no new question

Answer (score 0):

> So if i know what all namespace for those 5 elements i can put in one
>   xml file and can retrieve from that XML file. or as you mentioned can
>   define those name space in global document.

If you have a map of which namespace to use with which "root" element name, you could just as well keep it in the stylesheet itself.

Here's an example (using made-up namespaces, since you did not specify your own):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:ns-map>
    <ns root="GetImageRequest">urn:webservice/a/b/GetShoeboxItem</ns>
    <ns root="SaveShoeBoxitemRequest">urn:webservice/c/d/SaveShoeBoxitemRequest</ns>
    <ns root="SaveClaimWithReceiptRequest">urn:webservice/e/f/SaveClaimWithReceiptRequest</ns>
    <ns root="GetThumbNailImageRequest">urn:webservice/g/h/GetThumbNailImageRequest</ns>
    <ns root="AttachReceiptwithExistingClaimRequest">urn:webservice/i/k/AttachReceiptwithExistingClaimRequest</ns>
</my:ns-map>

<xsl:variable name="root" select="name(/request/payload/*)"/>
<xsl:variable name="ns" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:ns-map/ns[@root=$root]"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="request/payload/*" />
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:element name="get:{local-name()}" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```